# SQL Groovy - context.expand custom properties error ORA-01756

Tags: sql, oracle, groovy, soapui

Attempting to run a sql statement within groovy and store the result into the def variable but encountering the following error message:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly
>   terminated.

This is my sql statement:

```
def Indicator = sql.firstRow("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REQUEST WHERE REQD_IND IS NOT NULL AND CUST_FORENAMES = '" + context.expand('${#Project#Forename}')+ "'AND CUST_SURNAME = '" + context.expand('${#Project#Surname}'));
```

When I run the statement without the `sql.firstRow` function it returns the entire select statement in the log but is able to access the custom property fine however it is the result I am after i.e. true/false

Answer (score 2):

The **ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated** is because the last `'` in your `SELECT` is missing.

To avoid the error and to keep the `SELECT` clear, I recommend to use [`firstRow(String sql,List<Object> params)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#firstRow(java.lang.String,%20java.util.List)) method instead:

```
def indicator = sql.firstRow(
    '''SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM REQUEST 
    WHERE REQD_IND IS NOT NULL 
    AND CUST_FORENAMES = ?
    AND CUST_SURNAME = ?''',
    [context.expand('${#Project#Forename}'),context.expand('${#Project#Surname}')])
```

Furthermore if you want to get only the number of rows use a alias for the `COUNT(*)` and get it back from the result returned by `firstRow` method:

```
def indicator = sql.firstRow(
    '''SELECT COUNT(*) as count
    FROM REQUEST 
    WHERE REQD_IND IS NOT NULL 
    AND CUST_FORENAMES = ?
    AND CUST_SURNAME = ?''',
    [context.expand('${#Project#Forename}'),context.expand('${#Project#Surname}')])

// use the alias to get simply the number
def count = indicator.count
```

Comment: Never never never substitute parameters in sql using string concatenation or string formatting...

Comment: @frenzykryger I don't do this on the sql, neither concatenation or formatting... I use the groovy param facilities substitution, it's the OP in his question who concatenate the strings.

Comment: I'm not about your solution (which does right thing) but about initial version which caused the question.

Comment: @frenzykryger ahhh ok, excuse me for my misunderstanding `:)`

Comment: Thank you both very much for your recommendations. Could i ask for more information regarding the 'groovy param facilities substitution' as i am new to groovy and sql and if there is a better way then i would prefer to use that :)

Comment: @user610 To avoid [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks it's better to avoid string manipulation on `SELECT`s. Typically and attacker can hack your select though these params.The way to go is avoid string manipulation and use params like I did in the answer using for example `firstRow(String sql,List<Object> params)` method (normally this kind of methods take care of this problems for you). Anyway I didn't make a remark on this since I think that you're using *SOAPUI* for your own integration test... so in this case there is no worries about an a possible attack.

Comment: @user610 and if the answer helps you think about [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
def forename = context.expand('${#Project#Forename}')
def surname = context.expand('${#Project#Surname}')
def indicator = sql.firstRow("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REQUEST WHERE REQD_IND IS NOT NULL AND CUST_FORENAMES = $forename AND CUST_SURNAME = $surname");
```